# How is the header of a block formatted in heap?

Tags: memory, system, heap-memory

I know that in a 32 bit header, the most significant 29 bits are the number, and the least significant 3 bits indicate the block is free or allocated. But, I don’t understand why, for example in a block of 24 bits, the size is 0x018, and the 3 least significant bits are 0x001 when it's allocated, and the header becomes 0x019. Why is the header “0x019”? We’re not supposed to add these two?

Why is the header not "0x018001" instead?[image]

Comment: You are mixing binary with hexadecimal. 0x08 = binary 1000. 1001 is 0x09.

Comment: Can you give some detail of how it works?

Comment: Each hexadecimal digit represents 4 bits.

Comment: ok so, they're in 4 bits. If I convert 0x18 to base 2, it will be, 11000. Add 001 (indicate allocated)to the least significant side, and it becomes 11000 001. 11000 001 is 0xC1, not 0x19

Comment: read the part of the text where this scheme imposes a double-word alignment and the 3 lower bits of the size are always 0. The 3 lower bits of the size in the field are "0 0 a", and are used for the allocated/free flag. The "size" field is 32 bits long, not 29.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to say from your question where your misunderstanding lies.

In the example, `0x018` is decimal 24 and binary `11000`. This is the block size in bytes.

Because the `malloc` designer has chosen to allocate blocks with sizes that are multiples of 8-byte, *all* block sizes will end in 0 or 8 (binary 0000 or 1000). This means the low order 3 bits are always zero.

Rather than allocate an extra byte in the header just for the single bit that indicates whether the block is allocated or free, this design stores the 0/1 in the lowest-order bit, assuming that it can be masked out (with a bitwise "and", in C, `&`) when the block size is needed. This bit is "or"ed with the block size to get the header: `0x18 | 1`, which produces `0x19`. In binary, that's `11000 | 1 = 11001`.

I can't see why you think the size is shifted left.

More generally, if `h` is the 32-bit header value, then the block size is `h & ~0x7`, which can also be written `h & 0xfffffff8`, and the allocated flag is `h & 1`.

Similarly if you have a block size `z` and an allocated bit `a`, then the header is always given by `h = z | a` or, if you'd rather, `h = z + a`, just as shown above with the example values.

Comment: allocate blocks have sizes that are multiples of 8-byte. Why can't the block size be 16,32,64,etc? Why does it have to be 0 or 8?

Comment: oh I didn't quite understand what "|" is. That's what confused me. It is just  a "or" symbol.

Comment: @ronnLee They can be. I said bock sizes (in hex) _end_ in 0 or 8. All those numbers you mentioned end in 0 or 8. If the answer was helpful, it would be good to mark it accepted.